# How to more easily reference 3rd party sources in git?

Tags: git

About a year ago I implemented a git strategy to manage a 3rd party library based on talking to the community.  I was very new to git back then.  This required making an orphan node, adding the source and merging it into our source code.  The commands are as follows (from my notes):

```bash
cd /path/to/our/modified/source/directory              #1
git checkout --orphan vendor
rm -rf *                                               #2
cp -R /path/to/original/distribution/version/* .       #3
git add .                                              #4
git commit -m 'vendor vVersion'
git checkout merge-branch                              #5
rm -rf *
git reset --hard
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories -s ours vendor   #6
```

This results in the following history:

```
         ...A0--A1-...             dev
             \ /           
              C0                   merge-branch (transient)
             /           
            B0                     vendor
```

**Note** that the `merge-branch` is a transient branch that is removed after merging back into the `dev` branch.  [Schwern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14660/schwern) has called this a `feature` branch, but the name is irrelevant as it has no actual history.  It is a transient branch used only in the workflow.

The idea was that I would then add to the vendor branch and then merge again with the following commands (from my notes):

```bash
cd /path/to/our/modified/source/directory              #1
git checkout vendor
rm -rf *                                               #2
cp -R /path/to/original/distribution/version/* .       #3
git add .                                              #4
git commit -m 'vendor vVersion'
git checkout merge-branch                              #5
git merge vendor                                       #6
```

Resulting in:

```
         ...A0--A1-...-Ax--Ay--... dev
             \ /        \ /
              C0         Cz        merge-branch (transient)
             /          /
            B0---...---Bw--...     vendor
```

It is now time to add a new version of the 3rd party source.  However, it would seem that the *vendor* branch is gone, or my notes are wrong. I found that if it wasn't for the commit message, I might not have been able to find the branch at all.  The `B` branch is supposed to be running in parallel to the main source branch `A`. However, now that I think about this, I'm not sure how this is done.

I could change `git checkout vendor` to `git checkout <B0-hash>`, but that doesn't make sense as `B0`'s version of our source would be that of `A0`.  So how would I update it to version `Ax`?  Or is there something I'm missing that I didn't write down at the time?

Comment: `...as B0's version of our source would be that of A0...`  Uh, no, if you did what you described B0 doesn't *have* a version of your source.  I'm not sure why your vendor branch is gone, but if it weren't it would be at B0 - there is no mechanism nor need for it to advance as you make new A commits.  B0 is what you should use.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Not at my desk, but if I just deleted the vendor directory and not the rest as it shows in the notes, wouldn't the branch contain the other stuff eternal to the vendor directory? I think I messed up. Is there a way of fixing it?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger, ok, so yes, I did a `git checkout <B0-hash>` and can see the rest of our files in the folder.  Is there a way to remove them so this will work properly?  At the time I had put in the base version, and then did a merge of the next version.  There were a lot of conflicts so I don't really want to do this process again.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger, I was wrong.  Should have used `git show --pretty="" --name-only <B0-hash>`.  It shows only the 3rd party source.

Comment: The only thing I needed was to give it a branch name.  That was easy to accomplish by checking out the latest node in `B` and then doing a `git checkout -b vendor`.  I panicked for no reason.

Comment: Is this vendor code just a library dependency? Or is it some other version of your code?

Comment: @Schwern, 3rd party library dependency external to our code.

Answer (score 1):

## Make a vendor *clone*

Rather than maintaining a vendor branch, maintain a vendor *clone*. Make your own git clone of the 3rd party library. Patch it and keep it up to date just like a fork of any other repository. This cleanly separates maintaining your project from maintaining your fork of the 3rd party library. You can run its full test suite on your changes, easily pull updates from upstream, and even share your work upstream.

Once you have your 3rd party library in its own repository you can manage it as a dependency using existing tools.

## Use a dependency manager

This 3rd party library is a dependency, and dependencies are better handled by dependency managers than Git hacks. A good dependency manager will solve this any many other problems for your project.

Which you use depends on your language, framework, and circumstances. Many can depend directly on your Git clone and even specific branches and tags. For example, here is [Ruby's Bundler](https://bundler.io/v1.17/guides/git.html) depending on `nokogiri` pulling from the Git repository at `https://github.com/rack/rack.git` and its `rack-1.5` branch.

```
gem 'nokogiri', git: 'https://github.com/rack/rack.git', branch: 'rack-1.5'
```

If your dependency manager doesn't handle Git repositories, it might be able to build from a tarball or you might have to make packages. It's worth it.

## Git submodules

If no suitable dependency manager is available you can use [Git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). Link your vendor clone into your project as a submodule.

```
git submodule add https://git.example.com/3rdparty/project_name vendor/project_name
```

Now `vendor/party_project/` will appear as a subdirectory in your project containing the 3rd party library. You can control which commit is checked out and update it as you need.

Submodules do make your project a bit harder to work with. A real dependency manager is preferred.

Comment: Submodules won't work as the 3rd party source is not managed on a git repo (at least not an accessible one). Might look into project dependency managers, but this is almost a year old, so I'm not going to change it now without an extremely good reason, and only if it can be placed on top of what was already done. Can they do that?

Comment: @Adrian I'm not sure what you mean by "placed on top of what has already been done". If you mean to keep your vendor branch hack, that defeats the point. This replaces the hack. If you mean to keep the *contents* of the vendor branch, yes that can be extracted and moved to a new repository. As for where the 3rd party source is located, it does need to be somewhere accessible to users of your project. The extremely good reason to make this change is that your current hack is unmaintainable even by yourself, and will be less so by someone after you. Dependency managers are well documented.

Comment: I'm all for more maintainable. However, I may not have understood your earlier question, so just to confirm, this will allow for our modifying of the code independent of the 3rd party vendor, which may never see these modifications?

Comment: @Adrian Yes. Instead of a vendor branch, maintain a vendor *clone*. Clone the vendor's repository and patch it as you like. Depend on your clone, either via a dependency manager or as a submodule. This cleanly separates maintaining your project from maintaining the dependency. I'll update the answer to make this more clear.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still unclear. The way I'm currently doing this, I have the original source and our modified source, leaving the original untouched. When the original source is updated, we can then merge it into our updated source, tweaking it here and there when there are merge conflicts. How is that done using your method? Please forgive me if I'm looking dense. It took me a while, asking a lot of Qs to get where I am now. Before I switch over, I need to make sure I understand what the entire control process is, and how it looks from git. If I don't understand it, then I can't explain it.

Comment: @Adrian Make a clone of the original (aka "upstream") source repository for the 3rd party library, like a [Github fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/). This is the "vendor clone". Do all your tweaks in your vendor clone.

Comment: And when the next iteration comes in from the vendor, what then?  How do I merge it without wiping out our changes?

Comment: @Adrian Like any other fork, you `git pull` changes from the upstream repository. This fetches the changes from upstream and merges them into your local branch. It is, essentially, the same as maintaining a vendor branch, but isolated in its own repository. See [Syncing A Fork](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/), [Git Branching - Remote Branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches), and [Distributed Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows).

Comment: So our vendor repo is the "upstream" one that we update with the vendors source and will pull from into our main repo which we modify?  This is getting clearer and sounds like a good idea as it does the same thing as I am doing, except it is doing it in separate repos.  I wish someone could have stated this sooner.  However, what is the point of the dependency manager?

Comment: @Adrian "Upstream" refers to the original 3rd party library's repository. Your vendor clone pulls from this "upstream" source. Otherwise, yes, you've got it. A good dependency manager will allow you to treat your clone of the vendor library like any other package dependency... assuming the vendor library is a well behaved package in the first place. Then you don't have to mess around with Git submodules; dependencies, including your vendor clone, will be fetched as part of the normal build process.

Comment: There is no vendor repo.  We get the files in batches.

Comment: @Adrian In that case you'll have to commit the upstream changes to your vendor repo manually. You'll want to keep them in a vendor branch and update your own branch from that. Again, it's very similar to what you're doing now, except it's managed in its own repository.

Comment: Ok, so now how do I migrate what I have already done (having an internal repo) to an external repo?

Comment: @Adrian I don't fully understand what's in the current repo? Is it *just* the vendor code with your patches? Or is there also the project which is using the vendor code? What's in `dev`?

Comment: `vendor` has 2 versions of their code.  What we had before upgrading, and what we upgraded to.  `dev` has our code and their code (with mods) before the upgrade, and our code and theirs (with mods) after the upgrade.  Given what you were saying, this would be similar except that `vendor` would be an external repo.  It would be quite a PITA to have to do the merge again without history as it was very difficult doing it the first time.

Comment: @Adrian I originally thought you'd mixed the 3rd party library into a larger project which dependency on it. If you're just maintaining patches to a 3rd party library, I'd have a `vendor` branch to store their code and a `dev` branch to store your patches. Commit their updates to `vendor` and then merge `vendor` into `dev`. I don't see a need for a `merge-branch`.

Comment: `merge-branch` is a transient branch which then destroyed after a merge takes place. As we do peer code reviews, we need that so that others can look over the code prior to committing it to `dev`.

Comment: `Commit their updates to 'vendor' and then merge 'vendor' into 'dev'.`  Sorry, isn't that what I'm already doing?

Comment: @Adrian What you're doing with `merge-branch` would normally be done with a feature branch. The way you've drawn its connections is a bit funny. [Here's an illustration of how the normal feature branch flow would apply to a vendor branch](https://gist.github.com/schwern/e6044b669ba85700ced081a6a8c9010f).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183034/discussion-between-adrian-and-schwern).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the latest node in `B` branch and then run the command `git checkout -b vendor`.  This will make that node the HEAD of the `vendor` branch.  Everything else should work as normal.